# Perl6: First array element places into string, 2nd fails to place into string

Tags: raku, string-interpolation

I'm trying to make a new string from array elements thus:

```
my $truth = "s3://dir/@d[$d1]/$plate/@d[$d1].$plate.delta";
```

but the issue is that this gives

`s3://dir/pgr_9/1/@d[0].1.delta`

when it should give

`s3://dir/pgr_9/1/pgr_9.1.delta`

Why isn't this array element `@d[0]` interpolating into the string `$truth`? How can I get it to?

Comment: Eugene has this case covered; P6 can interpolate method calls and that's what's tripping things up here when it realizes you *don't* mean a method call. In general, P6 does a balancing act when deciding whether a part of a string is meant to be what you literally type or whether it's meant to be interpolated. In practice you'll quickly see if it's doing what you intend. If you write code that gets treated as literal text, a generic solution is to put it inside braces. For example, in extremis, in this case you could write `my $truth = "s3://dir/{@d[$d1]}/{$plate}/{@d[$d1]}.{$plate}.delta";`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure about the reason (probably `$plate.delta` is regarded as a method call?), but escaping the dot before `delta` solves the problem.

```perl6
my $plate = 1;
my $d1 = 0;
my @d;
@d[0] = "pgr_9.1";

say "s3://dir/@d[$d1]/$plate/@d[$d1].$plate\.delta";
```

**Output:**

```perl6
s3://dir/pgr_9.1/1/pgr_9.1.1.delta
```